# Upgrading MySQL 5.6 to 5.7 and extreme slow queries with WHERE IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database, amazon-rds, mysql-5.7

After upgrading to MySQL 5.7 (from 5.6) with Amazon RDS, some queries that use A TONS of ids (42k+) inside the IN CLAUSE started to get much slower.

**Query**

```sql
SELECT (`sales_contact_emails`.`contact_id`) AS `_prefetch_related_val_contact_id`,
       `sales_email`.`id`,
       `sales_email`.`type`,
       `sales_email`.`email`
FROM `sales_email`
         INNER JOIN `sales_contact_emails` ON (`sales_email`.`id` = `sales_contact_emails`.`email_id`)
WHERE `sales_contact_emails`.`contact_id` IN (/* 42000+ different IDs in here */);
```

**SHOW CREATE TABLE**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `sales_contact_emails` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `contact_id` (`contact_id`,`email_id`),
  KEY `email_id_refs_id_5cebc930` (`email_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26433420 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `sales_email` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `sales_email_idx_email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=189951028 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Explain MySQL 5.6**

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | sales_contact_emails | range | contact_id,email_id_refs_id_5cebc930 | contact_id | 4 | NULL | 41376 | Using where; Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | sales_email | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | company.sales_contact_emails.email_id | 1 | NULL |

Profile (First run after reboot):

| Status | Duration |
| --- | --- |
| starting | 0.011993 |
| checking permissions | 0.000010 |
| checking permissions | 0.000006 |
| Opening tables | 0.006008 |
| init | 0.005540 |
| System lock | 0.000013 |
| optimizing | 0.001441 |
| statistics | 0.042569 |
| preparing | 0.001433 |
| executing | 0.000008 |
| Sending data | 0.051343 |
| end | 0.000009 |
| query end | 0.000007 |
| closing tables | 0.000010 |
| freeing items | 0.001068 |
| cleaning up | 0.000417 |

**Explain MySQL 5.7**

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | sales_contact_emails | NULL | index | contact_id,email_id_refs_id_5cebc930 | contact_id | 8 | NULL | 24978777 | 50 | Using where; Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | sales_email | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | company.sales_contact_emails.email_id | 1 | 100 | NULL |

Profile (First run after boot):

| Status | Duration |
| --- | --- |
| starting | 0.015114 |
| checking permissions | 0.000014 |
| checking permissions | 0.000004 |
| Opening tables | 0.000019 |
| init | 0.007370 |
| System lock | 0.000023 |
| optimizing | 0.001555 |
| statistics | 0.024513 |
| preparing | 0.001390 |
| executing | 0.000006 |
| Sending data | 148.873194 |
| end | 0.000012 |
| query end | 0.000010 |
| closing tables | 0.000008 |
| freeing items | 0.001544 |
| cleaning up | 0.000711 |

Profile (Second run)

| Status | Duration |
| --- | --- |
| starting | 0.014875 |
| checking permissions | 0.000012 |
| checking permissions | 0.000005 |
| Opening tables | 0.000019 |
| init | 0.006042 |
| System lock | 0.000015 |
| optimizing | 0.001538 |
| statistics | 0.023283 |
| preparing | 0.001399 |
| executing | 0.000007 |
| Sending data | 6.101950 |
| end | 0.000013 |
| query end | 0.000009 |
| closing tables | 0.000008 |
| freeing items | 0.000996 |
| cleaning up | 0.000438 |

**Facts**

- About 25 million rows in the `sales_contact_emails` table.
- `contact_id` index is a compound index (contact_id, email_id) with extremely high cardinality. It's effectively an unique index. `SHOW INDEXES` below:

| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sales_contact_emails | 0 | contact_id | 1 | contact_id | A | 24976228 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |
| sales_contact_emails | 0 | contact_id | 2 | email_id | A | 24601066 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |

- The minimum id value for the IN CLAUSE is `43890973` and the highest value is `43839266` (difference of about 51k). Sweet spot for a `range scan` I suppose. This matches (kind of) the estimation for the MySQL 5.6 explain plain.
- MySQL Versions: `5.6.44` vs `5.7.33`
- The difference between the two explain plans is the `type=range vs type=index` and the huge estimation for `rows`.
- Using RDS for both examples. Same snapshot (one is migrated to MySQL 5.7 of course).
- Using default Parameters/Options Groups for both engines.
- 0 traffic, only myself and my query benchmark.
- The actual SQL statement is about 400KB.

**Research so Far**

- https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87164: It seems that there's a bug with IN CLAUSES on MySQL 5.7, but this may not be related to my specifc case. I tried the same snapshot for MySQL 8 and got the same performance from 5.7
- tried to disable/enable all @@optimizer_switch (full off and full on)
- tried to play with `@@eq_range_index_dive_limit` (50k instead 200 and no difference)

**Questions**

- What behavior changed on MySQL 5.7 that made those kind of queries so slow?
- Is there any way to change the behaviour back to the old way to get similar performance with **none or minimal** change in the query structure?

**Focus**

I know that an IN CLAUSE with 42k itens may be a problem itself, and there are workarounds for that (subqueries, joins, temporary tables...), but **that's not the question** at the momment. The focus is MySQL 5.7 vs 5.6 engine/optimizer/query-planner different behaviours.

---

Thanks in advance, :)

Comment: (Meanwhile, Profiling is crap; don't bother using it.)

Comment: Also, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @RickJames I've added the info as requested. And indeed, there was only a single time where the Profiler helped me with something, but I always have hope. LOL.

Comment: Does `sales_contact_emails` need the `id`?  If not, get rid of it completely and promote the `UNIQUE KEY` to be the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: File a bug report ("regression") about the Optimizer -- bugs.mysql.com

Comment: @RickJames kind of, ORM stuff, it may have some code side effects, so It would be "undesirable". Anyway, I'll try to fill a bug report. Do I need to have a script to generate the data, or is this report good enough?

Comment: It would be better to have self-contained SQL -- CREATE TABLEs, INSERTs, SELECTs.

Comment: @GeorgePatrick If I remember correctly, we had to adapt: change queries. In the end we tried to be as vanilla as possible and removed all the custom switches. No easy answer unfortunately. :/